# Rails Devise and rails_admin authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

This is a 2 part question:

*Part 1*

My Users have an admin boolean and one of them is true (ie one user is an admin). How can I authenticate the controller below to only allow this admin user to access Create, New, Destroy, Edit, etc

```
class NewsOutletsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @news_outlets = NewsOutlet.all
  end

  def show
    @news_outlet = NewsOutlet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @news_outlet = NewsOutlet.new
  end

  def create
    @news_outlet = NewsOutlet.new(news_outlet_params)

    @news_outlet.save
    redirect_to @news_outlet
  end

  def edit
    @news_outlet = NewsOutlet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @news_outlet = NewsOutlet.find(params[:id])
    if @news_outlet.update news_outlet_params
      redirect_to @news_outlet
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def delete
  end

  def destroy
    @news_outlet = NewsOutlet.find(params[:id])
    @news_outlet.destroy
    redirect_to news_outlets_path
  end  

  private

  def news_outlet_params
    params.require(:news_outlet).permit(:name, :url)
  end
end
```

*Part 2*

I also have rails_admin and the /admin address. I tried looking at other questions but none of the answers worked for me. How can I make only my admin user access the /admin dashboard?

Apologies if this is a repeat but I've spent 3 days on this already and couldn't find any comprehensive answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088486/best-way-to-do-permissions-checks-in-controllers) like this that has been made before.

This is a well-known problem resolved already by the community. Use an authorization framework.